# Not able to download multiple dynamoDB tables by using dynamodump

Tags: backup, amazon-dynamodb

Not able to download multiple dynamoDB tables by using dynamodump

$ python dynamodump.py -m backup -r us-east-1 -s 'DEV_*'

INFO:root:Found 0 table(s) in DynamoDB host to backup:

INFO:root:Backup of table(s) DEV_* completed!

But i'm able to download if i give single table name and "*" (download all DynamoDB tables).

I have followed this procedure which is in the below link:
https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump

Can anyone suggest me how to download multiple dynamoDB tables with the specific pattern (like QA_* / DEV_* / PROD_* / TEST_*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for i in `aws dynamodb list-tables | jq -r ''| grep 'QA*'| tr ',' ' ' | cut -d'"' -f2`;

do

echo "======= Starting backup of $i `date` =========="

python dynamodump.py -m backup -r us-east-1 -s $i

done

The above script will work if you want to take multiple dynamoDB tables backup. prior running the script you have to download the jq: (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)